# How To generate scripts (like we do in sql server) without data using oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In sql server, when we do generate scripts we can choose only schema. Likewise I tried to export the schema by clicking "Tools --> Database Export" from oracle sql developer but it comes along with insert command. How can I export just the schema without the data of a database from oracle sql developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in "Export Wizard", you have two "general" options:

- Export DDL - that checkbox should be checked
- **Export Data** - that checkbox should be **emptied** --> this is what you need

The rest should do.